# Is it possible to call a function in a different, but currently executing process?

Tags: windows, winapi, automation, build-automation, ipc

I have a friend who's working at a company that offers pretty poor support for its developers (scoring a 1/12 on the [Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html)).

Their build process is locked down pretty tight, and depending on the size of project it could take 40+(x2) mouse clicks to deploy. So I thought,  "Hey, why not automate it the clicks using the win32api?" (Specifically using Python). I've got him a real nice tool that works just fine except for one issue - the tool that they use has a navigation pane that may or may not be open.

You can open and close it with a button press, but I'm not sure how I could make sure it was either open or closed. It's irrelevant to the build process - the only problem is that it alters where the mouse needs to click on the screen depending on its open status. The application is written in .NET and it exposes a function call that applications are able to use to toggle the panel, so I've been looking around for ideas and so far I've got two of them:

- Attach to the process via a debugger and execute the function call somehow.
- Take a screenshot at the location of the panels titlebar (which I've got through the win32 API and doesn't appear to change regardless if the panel is hidden or not).

Is there an easier way to figure out the state of this panel? The developers are given an admin account on their machine in addition to their regular account, so I can entertain ideas that require admin access, though I don't think that should be necessary?

**UPDATE:**
It looks like there's a button that can close the pane. In UIAVerify something shows up as "text" "Navigation" "btnClose". It says its AutomationId is `btnClose` but it's a ControlType.Text

Comment: The "simple" way to automate interaction with a UI is to use the [Windows UI Automation APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis, Looks like the target application would need to implement the dll, no? In this case it would be easier to re-write the whole process, from what I understand.

Comment: Not necessarily.  UI frameworks like WPF and Windows Forms implement the automation interfaces for all of (most of?) the standard, built-in controls, so unless there is a lot of custom UI (e.g., your own `Button` type completely unrelated to the framework's `Button` type), UIA would be a good place to start.  I'd recommend downloading [UIAVerify](http://uiautomationverify.codeplex.com/) and seeing what the UI of the program exposes.

Answer (score 0):

What technology is this panel built from? Is it standard GDI or WPF? If its GDI, it should have a HWND. You should be able to find this HWND through either a class name or window title. Once you have the HWND, you can get its width.
If its built with WPF, er, I have no idea, but Snoop does this kind of thing, so I know its possible.

Comment: I suspect it's GDI - it's written in VB or C# .NET.